# window.onbeforeunload refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

I have a page that I do not want the user to go back, I want the page to refresh. I have been trying window.onbeforeunload with out success. Does anyone have any ideas?

Code I am trying

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
 document.location.reload();

};
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: That's not going to work, it would be annoying as hell if you couldn't leave a page when you wanted to. All you're allowed to do is pop up a confirm box.

Comment: You'll need a backend script like `php` to do something like preventing the user from going back to a page.You'll need to write some code in the controller.I believe that's the way in which bank transactions work.

Comment: @adeneo - We have our reasons why we want to stop the back button from working. Thanks for your input.